# Trying to prevent race conditions with pselect(), but signal won't interupt

Tags: c++, signals

I am currently trying to implement a server in C++ using sockets. I am trying to prevent race conditions by blocking the SIGINT signal until it is stuck in the blocking pselect. From there, it should be exiting, changing my loop variable, and then quitting the thread. From my attempts at getting this working, it appears that it reaches the pselect(), but it does not get interrupted using my code. Any help is appreciated.

Listener.h:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

class CListener
{
public:
    CListener();
    void quitListener(void);

private:
    void* InitListener(void);
    static void* StartListenerThread(void* context);

    static bool mbListening;
    pthread_t mtThreadID;
};
```

Listener.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "Listener.h"

bool CListener::mbListening = true;

CListener::CListener()
{
    mbListening = true;
    mtThreadID = 0;
    pthread_create(&mtThreadID, NULL, &CListener::StartListenerThread, this);
}

void* CListener::StartListenerThread(void* context)
{
    return ((CListener*)context)->InitListener();
}

void* CListener::InitListener()
{
    sigset_t tSignalSet;
    sigset_t tOriginalSignalSet;

    sigemptyset(&tSignalSet);
    sigaddset(&tSignalSet, SIGINT);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &tSignalSet, &tOriginalSignalSet);

    FD_ZERO(&tConnectionSet);
    FD_SET(0, &tConnectionSet);

    while(mbListening)
    {
            tSelectSet = tConnectionSet;
            std::cout << "Reached pselect\n";
            nReadyConnections = pselect(nSelectSocket+1, &tSelectSet,
                                    NULL, NULL, NULL, &tOriginalSignalSet);
            std::cout << "Broke out of pselect\n";
            if(nReadyConnections < 0 && errno == EINTR)
            {
                mbListening = false;
            }
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return NULL;
}

void CListener::quitListener()
{
    raise(SIGINT);
}
```

As long as I copied everything correctly *fingers crossed* you should just be able to run:

```
CListener tListener = CListener();

usleep(20000);

tListener.quitListener();
```

and the outputs should be displayed in terminal. My end goal is that I can allow for pselect to be interrupted without breaking any processing that may come after and allowing the thread to close gracefully. (blocking at pselect > recieve SIGINT > interupt pselect > return to loop > finish up and exit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my own problem. Since I am generating a thread, I needed to add functions that allow for that, as well as adding a signal handler, like shown below.

```
void CListener::quitListener()
{
    pthread_kill(mtThreadID,SIGINT);
}

void CListener::installSIGINTHandler()
{
    signal(SIGINT, CListener::SIGINTHandler);
}

void CListener::SIGINTHandler(int signo)
{
    mbListening = false;
}
```

And needed to change the sig mask setup to this:

```
pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &tSignalSet, &tOriginalSignalSet);
```